# How to write cron file for upload local files into s3 bucket at every hours in django rest framework

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-s3, cron, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework, I can upload files into 'local path' or 's3 bucket' directly. 
My Question is first I want to upload files into local path and after specific time (e.g one hour) I want to upload it into s3 bucket. But in API GET should be display the s3 bucket path url for files.
If anyone have with any example codes or documentation, please comment

Comment: Have you tried using https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/ ?

Comment: in my opinion, better is try celery for create task automatic running for push file to s3. Its better for user and better for system performance. Celery in here http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html